# When access image file throgh url it redirects to page not found page in drupal6

Tags: .htaccess, drupal, drupal-6

I am using drupal6 for my website. When i try to access the image url like `mysite.com/sites/default/files/aisle-mapper/web-icon Aisle Mapper.png` through browser the link redirects to `mysite.com/aisle-mapper/web-icon%20aisle%20mapper.png` and shown page not found message. Becuase of this issue lot of images are not loading in my site. When i remove all the capital letter from the image name the image is loading properly. Is there any issue in drupal to provide the image name with capital letter.

The issue is only in my website it is working perfectly on my localhost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be caused by the `pathauto` module.In `Administer › Site building › URL aliases` you can find the `automated alias settings` tab.Under that go to the `general settings` area.You might have set `character case` set to `change to lowercase`.Hope that might be your problem.. :)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But i have change this setting still the same  problem

Comment: I think it might be caused by your .htaccess file or httpd.conf file.please do try checking those files.

Comment: my htaccess file is default drupal htaccess does'nt change anything.

Comment: I have tried by disabling my clean url but still have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and issue was, there was a space at the end of the image name! I removed it and it was working fine. So just make sure you image does not have any space at the end of its name!

Comment: But when upload the same image on another drupal project folder it can access. Anyway let me check it also and come back to you.